# moving cursor forward-sexp goes one char further in evil mode

Tags: evil, motion, sexp

When I want to highlight the following region

(a `( b ( c ) )` ) )

I get

(a `( b ( c ) ) )` )

I mark the beginning and do `forward-sexp` (or sp-forward-sexp, which results in the same outcome)

In, insert mode, I get the desired outcome, but in normal mode I get the 2nd outcome.

I tried   `(evil-set-command-property 'sp-forward-sexp :keep-visual t)`

(I remember it was hard to debug this, because hooks/advices are hard to track..)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dr-qubit.org/Evil_cursor_model.html

So vim has different model for cursor.

You can get the emacs behavior by removing the additional motion/visual cursor model.

by setting `inclusive` type equal to `exclusive` type.

I was trying to define new type

The fact that I coulnd't find how to fix this easily suggests that
evil mode is mostly for `vim` users not `emacs` users..

I thought i messed up my configuration, because it was hard to find any mention of the problem.